# Presence of a material-ui component at the top of the render method affects how subsequent components are styles

Tags: css, reactjs, tabs, themes, material-ui

I have created some styled components which were not rendering correctly for me, but on transferring the code to a codesandbox (which happens to have a material-ui button in the template) the components were rendering fine.  This is the code which renders as expected. I then figured out that the presence of a material-ui component at the top of the render completely changes the styling that is applied.   (the styling injected via the classes prop is not applied). Here is the code that renders ok:

```
 /**If I comment in either the Button or the card material-ui Component below, I have no problem seeing the 
 * styled components.  If either are present, the styling is awful.
 */
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">     
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
         Hello
      </Button>
        {/* <Card /> */}
      <MyTabs tabInformation={tabInformation} />
      <MyTabs tabInformation={tabInformation} altType={true} />
      <StyledTabs tabInformation={tabInformation} altType={false} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The styled components `MyTabs` themselves use a hattrick of a ConditionalThemeWrapper, the withTheme HOC (which overrides the material-ui styles and the withStyles HOC. though I am not sure this is relevant to the behaviour that I am seeing.

If I remove the `<Card/>` or `<Button/>` material-ui component (so neither are present) the styling injected via the classes prop is not applied, but I do not understand why. ( I can hack with !important to bump up the css priority, to see the styling but I know I shouldn't have to do this).

I am not able to reproduce this in a codesandbox, as whether the button/card component is there or not, the components render correctly.

I have pushed the code to a github repo at https://github.com/TaraMcC/tabsStylingError.git  Comment out the material-ui button to watch the tabs change styling.

Very grateful for any pointers!

Comment: Welcome @tmc! Can you explain what you mean by the 'styles break down'?

Comment: edited, thanks @BrettDeWoody. The css styling that is applied through the myTabs classes prop is not applied, so the tabs do not render as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in material-ui v3.9.2. I upgraded to (latest 4.8.3) and the rendering looks the same with or without the `<Card />` present.